# Why does crontab store my crontab under /var/spool/cron/crontabs/user instead of /etc/cron.daily

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04

I wanted to create a crontab doing some job for me.
Because my server isn't running 24/7 i decided to use `anacron` instead.

Ok, so I took a short look into `/etc/anacrontab`:

```
1       5       cron.daily      run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7       10      cron.weekly     run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly        15      cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

I saw that anacron is already executing the daily/weekly and monthly crontabs.

In my case I want to execute the command on a daily basis, so I focused on the first line where I can clearly see that `anacron` is executing all scripts in `cron.daily` every day with a delay of 5 minutes.

So I discarded the idea of creating an anacrontab or more likely an entry in `/etc/anacrontab` and intended to create a crontab which is placed in `cron.daily` because anacron will execute every script inside this folder anyway.

Now when I create a "daily"-crontab with:

```
crontab -e
```

regarding to `man crontab` the crontab is placed under `var/spool/cron/crontabs/user` instead of `/etc/cron.daily` where I was hoping the get my crontab into cron.daily getting executed by anacron.

**The questions**

1. Why is my intention wrong that my crontab is not automatically executed by anacron because it is not placed inside cron.daily.
2. Is the purpose of `cron.daily` just to include system and custom scripts and not crontabs itself.
3. Is the right way to get my job done to place a anacrontab inside `etc/anacrontab` instead of creating a crontab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really read the documentation, from man [crontab(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab)

> crontab - maintain crontab files for individual users

The crontab -e command edits the current user's [crontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) file which is found in (or created in) /var/spool/cron/crontabs/user.

If you want to run a file daily, all you have to do is put it in the /etc/cron.daily directory and ensure that the permissions are correct.

I wouldn't mess around with anacrontab if I were you.

Comment: I think I understand. So all I need to do is to place a bash script inside cron.daily??